# PHP opposite/reverse number

Tags: php

When I have a number `0,1` - how I can get `10`?

I think I can division it:

```
0,1 : 0,1 = 1
```

and then count numbers before comma: `**0,**1` and if I have this count, I should add one zero to this count: `1**0**`

Finally:

```
(0,1 / 0,1) * 1**0** = 10
```

But maybe exist easier way to do it?

Comment: Question: how exactly is 01 a number? Or do you mean 0.1?

Comment: I do recall some locale using comma as decimal separator.

Comment: any other case? 0.001 -> 1000?

Comment: @k97513 0.1 is 1/10 (as fraction)

Comment: @mrW yes, that's it.

Comment: You can just 1/0.1 or 1/0.01. You'll get 10 and 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

> 0.1 => 10

So

> 1 / 0.1 = 10